# Change an inline CSS style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there anyway I can change the inline style for this line of code dynamically based on screen size?

```
<div class="et_lb_module et_lb_column et_lb_resizable" style=" width: 20%;">
```

I would like to append or dynamically change the width: 20% to width: 100% - if the browser size is 786px or less but only on that specific class.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Many ways to do that... Just look for it!

Answer (score 4):

You could try using `window.matchMedia()` (among other approaches):

```
if (window.matchMedia('all and (max-width: 786px)') {
    $('div.et_lb_module.et_lb_column.et_lb_resizable').width('100%');
}
```

Or, given that you're using jQuery (and presumably want this to alternate between the two styles):

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('div.et_lb_module.et_lb_column.et_lb_resizable').width(
        window.matchMedia('all and (max-width: 786px)') ? '100%' : '20%'
    );
});
```

Incidentally, if that style were in a stylesheet, rather than in-line, you could simply use CSS:

```
@media (all and (max-width: 786px)) {
    div.et_lb_module.et_lb_column.et_lb_resizable {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
@media (all and (min-width: 786px)) {
    div.et_lb_module.et_lb_column.et_lb_resizable {
        width: 20%;
    }
}
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`window.matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia).
- jQuery:

  - [`resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/).
  - [`width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/).

Comment: @quantum: thank you for the typo-fix edit! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`window.matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia). Remember to add a media query listener so that it changes on more than just the initial window size. This should be much more efficient than binding to a resize event.

```
var div = document.querySelector(".et_lb_module.et_lb_column.et_lb_resizable");
var mql = window.matchMedia("screen and (max-width: 786px)");
mql.addListener(handleMediaQuery);
handleMediaQuery(mql);

function handleMediaQuery(mql) {
    if (mql.matches) {
        div.style.width = "100%"
    } else {
        div.style.width = "20%"
    }
}
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4p2rgjmm/)</kbd>

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Testing_media_queries for more info on using Javscript and media queries together.

Answer (score 0):

You could call the functions below, or you could append a function to the `on resize`method (if the browser width changes):

```
document.onresize = updateWidth;
```

Pure JavaScript:

```
function updateWidth(){

var widthFactor = 0.2;

if(window.innerWidth > 768){
     widthFactor = 1.0;
}

    document.getElementsByClassName("et_lb_module et_lb_column et_lb_resizable")[0].style.width= widthFactor * window.innerWidth + "px";
}
```

jQuery:

```
function updateWidth(){

var widthFactor = 0.2;

if(window.innerWidth > 768){
     widthFactor = 1.0;
}

    $("et_lb_module et_lb_column et_lb_resizable").css("width", (widthFactor * window.innerWidth));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like

```
if(screen.width > 786) {
    $('your_element').css('width', '100%');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).resize(function() {

    if( $(document).width() <= 768 ){
      $(".et_lb_module.et_lb_column.et_lb_resizable").css({ width: "100%" });
    } else {
      $(".et_lb_module.et_lb_column.et_lb_resizable").css({ width: "20%" });
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<div class="et_lb_module et_lb_column et_lb_resizable" style=" width: 20%;">
<script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      setSize($)
      $(window).resize(function(){setSize($)});
   });

   function setSize($){
      $('.et_lb_resizable').width(($(window).width() < 786 ? '100%' : '20%'));
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Javascript to do that. You can use plain CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .et_lb_module.et_lb_column.et_lb_resizable {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

Just tweak the selector to your liking.